# Error deploying ear to Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

We have a EAR with 3 EJB modules. I am trying to deploy to glassfish but am hitting an error I can't explain or work out how best to identify.

```
[#|2010-08-03T14:39:15.570+0100|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|[AutoDeploy] Selecting file /export/home/myapp/apps/domains/myapp/autodeploy/App-ear.ear for autodeployment.|#]

[#|2010-08-03T14:39:18.654+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/app/controller/IMessagingProcessor|#]

[#|2010-08-03T14:39:20.470+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|global|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Class [ Lcom/company/app/jms/IJmsSessionFactory; ] not found. Error while loading [ class com.company.app.eventprocessor.provider.EventProvider ]|#]
```

I have checked the classes mentioned in the ClassNotFoundException and they are definetly in a Jar in the ear and I have no compilation issues in eclipse/maven.

```
D:\Repository\App\AppEA\App-ear\target\App-ear.ear\CoreJms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\com\company\app\controller\IMessagingProcessor.class

D:\Repository\App\AppEA\App-ear\target\App-ear.ear\EventProcessor-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\com\company\app\eventprocessor\provider\EventProvider.class
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

James

Comment: Have a closer look in the full log file.  There should be more details there.

Comment: There is no more than the above in the server.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you're not getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, you're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` and I suspect some dependencies to be missing, as suggested by:

```
Class [ Lcom/company/app/jms/IJmsSessionFactory; ] not found. Error while loading [ class com.company.app.eventprocessor.provider.EventProvider
```

Where is that `com.company.app.jms.IJmsSessionFactory`?

---

> I have now cut the ear down to a single ejb module and am getting the NoClassDef for Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger however the log4j jar is also in the ear. It feels like I must be missing something fundamental here?

Where is the `log4j.jar` exactly? In `/lib`? Can you actually show the structure of your EAR? And please also show the `MANIFEST.MF` of your EJB-JAR.

Just in case, here is a relevant quote from [Packaging EJB 3 Applications](http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3670496_2/Packaging-EJB-3-Applications.htm):

> #### Packaging EJB-JAR
>
> ...
>
> The EJB-JAR file must include the
>   interfaces and bean classes. It may
>   also include any helper classes.
>   Optionally the helper classes may be
>   packaged in a separate JAR file in the
>   EAR file. You have two options:
>
> - The JAR containing helper classes may be packaged in the lib directory
>     of the EAR file. Using this approach,
>     the packaged classes will be
>     automatically visible to all modules
>     in the EAR module.
> - If you want to limit the visibility to only a specific EJB-JAR or WAR
>     module, you can create an entry in the
>     Manifest.mf file of the module that
>     contains a Class-Path attribute to the
>     JAR file.
>
> Now that you know the structure of
>   EJB-JAR and how to package it, let's
>   look at the elements of `ejb-jar.xml`.

---

> Based on your comments I think I am understadning my issue. It would appear I am not packaging the ear correctly, I don't think the maven dependencies are referenced correctly. If I simply build my ejb jar it does not include any of the dependant jars. Should I be specifying something in the pom to include the jars ejb-jar? I have the build plugin `<artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>` and packaging `<packaging>ejb</packaging>` set.

Bundling dependencies into an EJB-JAR is not supported (see [MEJB-3](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEJB-3)) mostly because jar-within-jar is not part of the [JAR specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) (and might not be supported by all EJB container) and does not comply with [Sun's advice regarding J2EE packaging](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html) in general.

So while you may ignore this rule (see [this trick](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEJB-3?focusedCommentId=203184&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_203184) or [this one](http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.com/2009/08/bundle-common-jar-into-ejb-jar-with.html)), the standard way would be to package the EJB-JAR and all the JARs it depends on in an EAR. This is my recommendation and I think that this post might help: [Because I always forget how to use maven-ear-plugin](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/because-i-always-forget-how-to-use-maven-ear-plugin/).

Comment: Sorry read one thing and typed another, that is in the ear as well though:

D:\Repository\App\AppEA\App-ear\target\App-ear.ear\CoreJms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\com\company\app\jms\IJmsSessionFactory.class

Comment: I have now cut the ear down to a single ejb module and am getting the NoClassDef for Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger however the log4j jar is also in the ear. It feels like I must be missing something fundamental here?

Comment: @James Please provide the requested information and ping me after update.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Based on your comments I think I am understadning my issue. It would appear I am not packaging the ear correctly, I don't think the maven dependencies are referenced correctly. If I simply build my ejb jar it does not include any of the dependant jars. Should I be specifying something in the pom to include the jars ejb-jar? I have the build plugin <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId> and packaging <packaging>ejb</packaging> set.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thanks to your answer I think I am almost there. I was not understanding the need to specifiy the dependencies in the ear pom I thought it would pick them up from the individual module pom's. I am getting, what I hope is, one last issue which I can't explain. This error:

javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.commad-1;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware|#]

is stumping me, I am not using the springframework and it looks like it is glassfish which requires this.

Any ideas?

Comment: @James To my knowledge, GlassFish doesn't use Spring. It must be something else. Are you sure this is not a transitive dependency of your code?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent based on your comment I have looked for a dependency and can't find one. I have looked at the dependency graph of the ear pom and nothing spring appears there. Even if I do a text search for 'springframework' in the project I get nothing. Is there any way to see what annotation the processing is failing on? Or anyway I can figure out what is going on here.

Comment: @James I have no idea from where this unsatisfied dependency is coming from. Could you paste the full log to http://pastie.org or something like that? (not sure I'll be able to help though).

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thank you for the help. I have narrowed down the issue and think it is because I am using activemq. I am just using the activemq-all jar which does not need any other dependancies, but I think there must be some annotations to the classes in the jar that have a depedency on spring. I am looking at ways to including the activemq jars in glassfish so I don't get this issue. Thanks